# PWA service worker updated at every refresh

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm registering service worker with the following updated callback:

```
updated() {
    alert('An update is ready. Please refresh the page.')
},
```

I make a minor change to the content of `service-worker.js` file to the browsers detect the change.

```
const version = 3.7;
```

When I deploy it I successfully get the updated alert but when I refresh I get it again. However I receive the new changes but I still get this alert which is not necessary anymore.

Comment: I think it's because I have open tabs and not using `skip waiting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fixed the problem

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  self.skipWaiting();
});
```